# Est-ce qu'il existe une nuance de prononciation du son "t" dans "petit ami" et "petite amie" ?

Tags: prononciation

On fait une liaison dans "petit ami" pour relier le "t" non prononcé avec le "a" = /pəti**t**ami/. Ici le son /t/ est devant une voyelle, donc il y a moins d'air qui sort de la bouche, comme dans le mot "table".

Et on fait un enchaînement dans "petite amie". À l'écrit c'est le même /pəti**t**ami/. Mais ici le son /t/ est déjà prononcé dans le mot "petite", avec plus d'air qui sort de la bouche par rapport au premier cas (parce qu'il n'est pas devant une voyelle, comme dans les mots "très" ou "patte").

Alors quand ce deuxième "t" est relié avec le "a", est-ce qu'on le prononce toujours avec plus d'air qui sort de la bouche (qui crée donc une nuance de prononciation entre "petit ami" et "petite amie") ? Ou ça devient le même son que le premier, avec moins d'air qui sort de la bouche ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les séquences ***petit ami*** et ***petite amie*** sont homophones<sup>1</sup> ainsi d'ailleurs que ***petit tamis*** (/p(ə.)ti.ta.mi/).

Je doute qu'une analyse poussée (oscillogramme/spectogramme) puisse détecter des variations de prononciation du *T* pour un même locuteur.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Le *E* final d'*amie* est cependant parfois prononcé : /amij/.</sub>

Comment: J'ai l'impression que pour certaines personnes il y a une différence de prononciation entre le "ie" de "amie" et le "i" de "ami". Cela dit le "t" semble bel et bien parfaitement homophone.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Oui. J'y ai pensé aussi et c'est pour ça que je me suis limité au *T*.

Answer (score 1):

Je n'imagine pas de différence ici. Il y a souvent des différences de prononciations entre les régions, le sud (zone de l'ancienne langue d'oc) élidant moins les "e muets". Mais ici, "petite amie" est une expression courante (signifiant plus ou moins fiancée, flirt, etc.) et même à Toulouse ou Marseille la prononciation est la même pour "petit ami" et "petite amie".

Answer (score 0):

Non-francophone ici, mais ayant passé beaucoup de ma vie à étudier cette langue. Je ne suis pas certain que, pour marquer une emphase, bien signifier le genre mâle de l'ami, certaines personnes ne diraient pas "p'ti ami" (sans le T de liaison).

Je souligne que je ne me rappelle jamais avoir noté consciemment cette prononciation, mais dans la langue parlée, chez les jeunes surtout, et sans doute depuis des décennies, déjà faire beaucoup de ces liaisons est considéré nul. Donc pour marquer une distinction importante d'une autre expression parallèle, j'imagine qu'on pourrait facilement omettre la liaison.

Evidemment, cette expression fait souvent partie d'une expression un peu plus longue et révélatrice : "mon/ton/son petit ami" notamment. Pour moi, faire sonner le "T" de liaison dans ces cas semble plus probable, pour la simple raison que le sexe de l'ami y est révélé, donc pas besoin de l'expliciter par la prononciation.

Je serais intéressé d'entendre les réponses de francophones...

Comment: Oui dira "p'ti ami" en parlant rapidement, mais quel que soit le genre "saptitami" "sonptitami", c'est à dire que ça ne change rien à la question :-)

Comment: *Petit ami* ami est le plus souvent la locution que tu évoques (mon/ton son petit ami) où petit n'a pas son sens originel, un petit ami, c'est un flirt, un fiancé. Je n'imagine pas que dans cette locution, le *T* puisse être escamoté par qui que ce soit. En tout cas, je l'ai toujours entendu. Ce qui peut sauter, c'est la première syllabe (*Son "titami"*). En revanche, je veux bien envisager l'hypothèse de quelqu'un qui, parlant d'amis de taille différentes, dirait "il est avec son **gran ami** et son **peti ami**", par symétrie.

Comment: @jlliagre Personellement je suis étonné qu'on puisse imaginer une utilisation **autre** que la locution en question. Ton idée d'une distinction entre "grand ami" et "petit ami" m'a fait rire franchement. Mais comme je dis, je ne suis pas francophone donc je m'en remets à ta situation d'autorité supérieure !

Comment: Ha ha, il n'y a pas d'autorité supérieure (aux autres) en terme de langue vivante parlée. Chaque locuteur natif est sa propre autorité. Plus j'y pense et plus je trouve /pəti ami/ improbable même dans le contexte de mon commentaire précédent. En revanche, /gʁɑ̃ ami/ est courant. Il doit souvent m'arriver de ne pas faire la liaison dans *C'est un grand ami à lui*.